# Why did Ramsay choose to attack this character?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the ninth episode of the sixth season of Game of Thrones "**Battle of the Bastards**" when the giant Wun Wun broke the gate of the castle, he got shot many times by archers and finally killed by the shot of Ramsay Bolton, my question is why did Ramsay wasted that shot on the giant when he has the chance to put it in Jon Snow's heart?